# Migrated questions. Is there a badge for that?

Tags: discussion, badges, migration

Badge suggestion: A badge for for having ten migrated, worthy but slighty out of scope, highly viewed or upvoted questions. Maybe call it the "Golden Goose" badge? Are there any badges for combined Stack site questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There's no badge for that because a migrated question generally indicates that you posted it in the wrong place initially. Badges are supposed to reward positive actions, not bad-but-not-that-bad.

All badges currently only take your actions on one site into account. The idea of cross-site badges has been floated around now and then on the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Note that most badge ideas have already been broached on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/badges), even quite silly ones. Yours is “[coconuts from mercia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22354)” which hasn't seen much attention.

Comment: No golden dunces cap? I was on my way... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the bronze badges Student and Scholar on the new site for a migrated question.  [I got the badges on Chemistry SE this way, for question migrated from Physics SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar?userid=16327).  Similarly [user “guest” got not only the Student but even the gold Famous Question badge on Sci Fi SE for a question migrated from Movies SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=53977).  [User “Jolly” got the Good Question silver badge on Sci Fi SE for a question that got highly upvoted after it got migrated from English SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/good-question?userid=1739).

Alternately if your question gets migrated to the Meta site, [you can get the Quorum bronze badge on the main site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/quorum?userid=71).